# Tkinter: Listbox please behave yourself

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, execution

```
import Tkinter
def selector():
    ...
    selections_scroller = Tkinter.Scale(b_action, from_=0, to=len(ymls))
    ...
    pos = int(selection.curselection()[0])
    loaded = ymls[pos]
    stuff_loaded = True
    p_cost.set(loaded[4])
    print loaded
    ...
def find_pos(event):
    selector()
selection.bind("<Button-1>", find_pos)
```

Now first and foremost note that this isn't all of the code so don't ask what the ymls are, they work normally. (They are bunch of tuples inside a list) I added these parts because in order for the listbox to print "loaded" succefuly I need execute "find_pos" twice. The first time I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
... (location) ...
pos = int(selection.curselection()[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

As far as I understand when executed the first time:

```
loaded = ()
```

But afterwards it returns the proper value. Why is it so? Please help and Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current selection is set by the class bindings. The class bindings fire *after* the widget-specific bindings. So, the first time your binding fires there is no selection. The second time it fires it will show whatever was previously selected.

You should bind on `<<ListboxSelect>>` if you want to do something when the selection changes. Binding on that means your code will work whether the user clicked on it or used the keyboard bindings.

Comment: @Bryan I found your answer useful. I changed from `<"Button-1">` to `<<ListboxSelect>>` and noticed that my program became sluggish. Does that ring any bell? Anything that might cause? Thanks.

Comment: @sedeh: no, I've never experienced a slowdown like you describe.